# add icon and separator to windows XP right click context menu

Tags: java, windows, registry, contextmenu

I need to add an icon to custom right click context menu and a  separator before and after the menu items i added to right click menu for windows XP,

I found some solutions that work for windows 7 but i an searching it for windows XP, Kindly help.

For example you we can see the image of Tortoise SVN also the separator before and after the menu item.

[image]

Comment: you need to do that with java?

Comment: @vivek_jonam No, like to do this using registry, but mentioned java as working on java application not C# or VB etc

Comment: *"custom right click context menu"*  To 'Open With'?

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes but it works for some options of my application like to sending/copy some options of my application, i upload an image for reff

Comment: OK no.  I have no idea had to add items to that menu.

Comment: http://www.favicon.cc/ is also a good image converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Add custom entry to Windows XP explorer context menu](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1674913)

and [this](http://www.askvg.com/a-complete-tutorial-to-customize-desktop-context-menu-in-windows-xp-using-resource-hacker/) might help you too.

You can customize the context menu using [Ultimate Windows Context Menu Customizer](http://www.door2windows.com/ultimate-windows-context-menu-customizer-customize-context-menu-in-windows-xp-vista-7/)