# How can I add an icon to the context menu in windows xp?

Tags: c#, windows-xp, registry, shell-extensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set icon for custom right-click context menu item for all desktop shortcuts (windows explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681032/set-icon-for-custom-right-click-context-menu-item-for-all-desktop-shortcuts-win)

[image: Context menu]

I have successfully created the Context Menu in Windows XP and I want to add icon to context menu as shown in Figure. I've read the literature on the Context Menu but failed. Can you help me? Thank you.

```
private void registryMenuContextFolder(string menuName, string pathApp, string pathIcon)

{

        try
        {

            RegistryKey _key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Folder\\Shell", true);

            RegistryKey _keyFolder = _key.CreateSubKey(menuName);
            if (_keyFolder != null)
            {
                _keyFolder.SetValue("Icon",Application.ExecutablePath +",0");

            }
            RegistryKey _keyCmd = _keyFolder.CreateSubKey("Command");
            if (_keyCmd != null)
            {
                _keyCmd.SetValue("", pathApp);
            }
            _keyCmd.Close();
            _keyFolder.Close();
            _key.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you use in order to create your context menu?

Comment: I registered in the Registry of Windows

Comment: Can you edit your question and detail the keys you added in the registry? Can't help you much without details...

Comment: I already posted the source on this article

Comment: This is not an option.  The ones you see with an icon are *shell extension handlers*.  You can't write those reliably in a .NET language.

Comment: Can you paste your whole registry subkey which is product of your code? You can do it by exporting key into text file.

Comment: Try to use responce from 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173011/add-icon-and-separator-to-windows-xp-right-click-context-menu